# Initialize unused values to 0 c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays

To initialize all values to 0 , we can do

```
int arr[5] = {0};
arr[1]     = 1  // index 1 is 1 all others contains value of 0
```

Is it possible to do something like that with dynamicly created array?

```
int m_size = 5;
int *one = new int[m_size]
```

especially , when i am reallocating array , using

```
if( i > m_size ){ // i as index
            int tmp = m_size;
            while( i > tmp){
                tmp*=2;
            }
            double *temp = new double[tmp];
            memcpy(temp,one,m_size);
            m_size = tmp;
            delete[] one;
            one = temp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want this like this (brackets at end):

`double *temp = new double[tmp]();`